# Depuración en visual studio code

Tags: javascript, funciones

Cuando realizó la depuración en visual studio code, en las variables `newPopularity` e `index` tiene un estado *undefined*. Agradezco su punto de vista sobre este bloque de código... el test no pasa por esa razón, ya que no actualiza el valor del popularity.

- Actualiza la propiedad <popularity> del accesorio,

  - Para eso deberás comprobar cuantos gatos visten el accesorio recibido por parámetros (es un id)
  - Si la cantidad de gatos que visten el accesorio son 2, entonces la popularidad del accesorio debe valer 'average'
  - Si la cantidad de gatos que visten el accesorio son 3 (o más), entonces la popularidad del accesorio debe valer 'high'
  - Si se actualizó la popularidad del accesorio, devolver un mensaje que diga `'La popularidad del accesorio <color_accesorio> <tipo_accesorio> fue actualizada a <popularidad>'`
  - Si no se actualizó la popularidad del accesorio, devolver un mensaje que diga `'No hubieron cambios en la popularidad del accesorio <color_accesorio> <tipo_accesorio>'`
  - Si el id de accesorio no existe arrojar un Error ('accesorio no encontrado' y no actualiza la popularidad).

```
 updateAccessoryPopularity: function (accessoryId){
    
      let accessory = accessories.find(acc => acc.id === accessoryId);
       if (!accessory) {
         throw new Error('accesorio no encontrado');
       }
     
       // Obtener la cantidad de gatos que visten el accesorio
       let numUsers = cats.filter(cat => cat.accessories.includes(accessoryId));
     
       // Actualizar la popularidad del accesorio según la cantidad de gatos que lo usan
       let newPopularity;
       if (numUsers.length >= 3) {
         newPopularity = 'high';
       } else if (numUsers.length === 2) {
         newPopularity = 'average';
       } else {
         newPopularity = accessory.popularity;
         return `No hubieron cambios en la popularidad del accesorio ${accessory.color} ${accessory.type}`;
       }
       
       // Actualizar la propiedad 'popularity' del objeto 'accessory'
       accessory = { ...accessory, popularity: newPopularity };
     
       // Actualizar la lista de accesorios en el objeto 'cats'
       let index = accessories.findIndex(acc => acc.id === accessoryId);
       accessories[index] = accessory;
     
       return `La popularidad del accesorio ${accessory.color} ${accessory.type} fue actualizada a ${newPopularity}`;
    }
```

Comment: cual seria tu problema puntual @JennyBuitrago?

Comment: @infinit3Loop__  Mi problema puntual es en las variables newPopularity e index, en la primera no me actualiza el valor de la propiedad (popularity) y aparecé undefined al igual que index, por lo mismo no pasa el test.

Comment: ● ---------- `updateAccesoryPopularity` ---------- › Actualiza la popularidad del accesorio dependiendo de cuantos gatos lo vistan
    assert.strictEqual(received, expected)
 Expected value to strictly be equal to:
      "La popularidad del accesorio White Sweater fue actualizada a high"
    Received:
      "No hubieron cambios en la popularidad del accesorio White Sweater"

    Message:
      expected 'No hubieron cambios en la popularidad…' to deeply equal 'La popularidad del accesorio White Sw…'Difference:

Answer (score 0):

Si sigues la lógica que está programada, el mensaje `"No hubieron cambios en la popularidad del accesorio..."` se va a devolver solo si el número de gatos es 0 o 1, cosa que no es parte de las especificaciones.

Por otro lado, el mensaje `"La popularidad del accesorio ... fue actualizada a ..."` se va a devolver independientemente de si la popularidad fue actualizada o no.

El problema es que estás mezclando la lógica de dos operaciones distintas. Una es determinar la popularidad en base al uso actual, y otra es determinar si esa popularidad debe actualizarse o no.

Para determinar la nueva popularidad, bastaría con:

```
let newPopularity;
if (numUsers.length >= 3) {
  newPopularity = 'high';
} else if (numUsers.length === 2) {
  newPopularity = 'average';
}
```

De esta rutina, `newPopularity` saldría definido solamente si se cumple con alguna de las condiciones dadas, y sería indefinido si no cumple con ninguna (el caso de haber 0 o 1 *usuarios*.  Aquí, la definición del problema nos falla, pues no dice qué valor utilizar en caso de que sea este el caso. Ante un mal planteamiento, tienes dos opciones: ir con el dueño de este problema y pedirle que lo defina (mi recomendación) o, inventar tú una solución cualquiera y pelear por que sea aceptada al haber una laguna en la especificación.

Supongamos que el dueño del problema resuelve ese problema y nos dice que en este otro caso usemos el valor `low`, entonces quedaría:

```
let newPopularity;
if (numUsers.length >= 3) {
  newPopularity = 'high';
} else if (numUsers.length === 2) {
  newPopularity = 'average';
} else {
  newPopularity = 'low';
}
```

Ahora, debemos determinar si esta popularidad es distinta a la que ya tiene el accesorio, pues es esto lo que define si la popularidad cambia o no.

Esto lo podemos lograr simplemente comparándolas:

```
if (accessory.popularity === newPopularity) {
  console.log("no cambia");
} else {
  console.log("si cambia");
  //cambiar la popularidad.
}
```

En caso que el dueño del problema no defina qué hacer en caso de haber 0 o 1 usuarios, entonces te tocará a ti decidir si quieres considerar esa condición como una donde no cambia la popularidad, o qué popularidad poner en caso que el accesorio ya tenga una, y ajustar el programa para que haga eso que has definido.

Finalmente, apuntar que para cambiar la popularidad no tienes que crear un nuevo objeto accesorio, lo puedes hacer directamente con el que ya tienes en la variable `accessory`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su valioso aporte. Voy a poner en práctica todo lo recomendado. Bendiciones